# What is the best way to get Mails using javamail API (fetch() or getMessages())?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I want to know what is the best way(load quickly the messages from the server) to get messages from one mailbox(e.g: INBOX, OUTBOX). I've found the folder feth() method and getMessages() method but I don't understand what is better between the two methods.

My current code use getMessages() method but it's still slow:

```
public static void fetch(String Host, String storeType, String user,
  String password) {
  try {
     // create properties field
     Properties properties = new Properties();
     properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
     properties.put("mail.imaps.host", Host);
     properties.put("mail.imaps.port", "993");
     properties.put("mail.imaps.starttls.enable", "true");
     Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
     // emailSession.setDebug(true);

     // create the IMAP store object and connect with the imap server
     Store store = emailSession.getStore("imaps");

     store.connect(Host, user, password);

     // create the folder object and open it
     Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
     emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
      System.in));

     // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
     Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
     System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);

     for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        Message message = messages[i];
        System.out.println("---------------------------------");
        writePart(message);
        String line = reader.readLine();
        if ("YES".equals(line)) {
           message.writeTo(System.out);
        } else if ("QUIT".equals(line)) {
           break;
        }
     }

     // close the store and folder objects
     emailFolder.close(false);
     store.close();

  } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (MessagingException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

}

Can someone explain me what's the right and the better way!

Answer (score 3):

The fetch method is use to prefetch message data in bulk.  Normally it's used to fetch and cache message metadata, headers, etc.  This is useful if you only need to examine a small amount of message metadata to determine whether to process a message.

You can also use the fetch method to fetch and cache the entire content of a message.  Unless you are accessing all the content of every message, you don't want to fetch the entire message using the fetch method.  When used that way it behaves more like the POP3 protocol except that it fetches multiple messages at once.  Obviously caching entire messages can use a lot of memory.

The getMessages method fetches no message data at all.  All it does is give you a "handle" through which you can access message data, which will be fetched on demand.  If you call the getSubject method, it will fetch the Subject (which is part of the "envelope" metadata).  You might want to use the fetch method to prefetch and cache this envelope data to make subsequent operations more efficient.  And when you decide you need to read the body or attachments of a message, that data will be fetched at that point.

Perhaps the fetch method should've been named prefetchAndCache.  :-)

Comment: Thanks you @Bill Shannon for your good explanations, now I understand the functionality of the fetch and getMessages methods. By your explanation, it's better to use POP3 protocol than IMAP to use fetch method or I'm wrong?

Comment: About the only time it's better to use POP3 is if you want to download all your email, delete it from the server, and close the connection as quickly as possible.  For almost everything else, use IMAP if you can.